# i cant install Tweak Tool

Tags: linux, debian

i tried

```
apt-get install unity-tweak-tool-daily
```

E : unable locate a package

and im tried gnome tweak tool

[gnome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XyTv.png)

Comment: Did u do `apt-get update` ?

Answer (score 0):

add repo before apt-get install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

reference http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/unity-tweak-tool-is-now-available-in-raring

Comment: That advice 1) is several years old and is no longer necessary on current Ubuntu systems, and 2) was never applicable for non-Ubuntu systems, like the OP's.

Comment: I currently don't use Ubuntu and I thought it is still in use. I remembered using this So I posted. Thanks :) @duskwuff

Comment: Sibi Raj :    see this image 
                    https://prnt.sc/ftg9y9

Comment: just try apt-get install unity-tweak-tool @KrdStudent